# Writing a recursive Preorder tree search that returns the answer as a list

Tags: java, tree

I have created the following Tree

```
T<Integer> t1 = new T(84, new T(48, new T(30), new T(50)),
                new T(96, new T(90), new T(1)));
```

What I am now trying to do is to sort the tree in pre order and returns the answer as a list.  My code sorts of work but I am building multiple lists rather than one single list.  My code is as follows:

```
    public static<E> List<E> porderlist(T<E> a) {


           if (a.isEmpty())
               return new List<E>();
            else {


            return new List(a.getValue(), new List(porderlist(a.getLeft()),     porderlist(a.getRight())));

   }
```

The output I get is `[84, [48, [30, []], 50, []], 96, [90, []], 1, []]`

When the output I want is `[84,48,30,50,96,90,1]`

Any clues as to how I can stop the nesting of the lists.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static<E> List<E> porderlist(T<E> a) {
    if (a.isEmpty())
        return new ArrayList<E>();
    else {
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
        list.add(a.getValue());
        list.addAll(porderlist(a.getLeft()));
        list.addAll(porderlist(a.getRight()));
        return list;
    }    
}
```